# Flash Builder 4.6 - Why am I not able to select anything in a spark Window component in design mode?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

In my Flash Builder (Flex) 4.6 app, I just noticed for some reason all my "s:Window" components will not allow me to click and select anything in design mode in flash builder!

My other non-window type components are fine - I can open a  TitleWindow or Group for example and click on the various fields and labels no problem.

In my Window components, I can select an item in the 'outline' window, but not using the mouse and actually clicking on the component in the visual design window.  When I click in there, it looks like it's selecting the actual 'window' box.  Almost like it needs to be 'sent to back' or something.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That used to happen to me when I have a container in front of all components.

```
<s:Button/>
<s:Button/>
<s:Button/>
<s:Group width=100% height=100%/>
```

Comment: Still no luck - I do not have any containers - it just a <s:Window> and inside I have <mx:FormItem>'s  and some <s:Button>'s and <s:CheckBox>'s.    When I click on anything, properties window shows that I am clicking on the s:Window, as if it's front-most.   I tried removing all my components, except 1 s:Label, no difference.  I tried adding everything in to a <s:Group>, no difference!  The only way I can get GUI edit ability is to change it from s:Window to s:TitleWindow, then change back after I am done editing.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same problem, there's someone asking the same question here:

[AIR: components in window-based mxml component are frozen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032610/air-components-in-window-based-mxml-component-are-frozen/9038010#9038010)

My suggestion so far is to use a `<mx:Window>` instead of `<s:Window>`
I hope that helps...I'm still looking for an appropriate answer on how to do it "the spark way"

Comment: A work-around I have been using is to temporarily change the tags to <s:TitleWindow> , do my design changes, then change the tags back to <s:Window> to compile.   A pain, but at least it's spark when it compiles.

Comment: Use the spark version of the `Window` component, as the MX version is set to be deprecated.