# AIR: components in window-based mxml component are frozen

Tags: apache-flex, air, window, components

SUBJ: creating a window-based mxml component, but in design mode all components that I'm adding are not movable, why? If I create component based on group f.e., it's ok, but based on window - they are frozen. Using Flash Builder 4.6

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a bug that Adobe needs to look into.

But in the meantime, you can use `<mx:Window>` and change them all to `<s:Window>` before you will finally build the release version of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and it's very frustrating.
I don't know whether it's a bug or not, but it happens in Flash builder 4.5 too.

What I figured out so far is that instead of using a `<s:Window>` you can actually use a `<mx:Window>`and then it will work as expected.

In the other hand I would like to be able to use the spark window instead. It's a very annoying tiny problem!